# Use of JComboBox and DefaultComboBoxModel in JAVA

Tags: java, combobox

I was tasked to create a panel with two comboboxes, the second combobox's item should rely on what was selected on the first combobox. Below is the code snippet of what I've done. I apologize if this was poorly written. It is my first time to do such things.

```
    // Sets up comboSearch and comboFor
    String[] searchList = {"Class", "Member", "Procedure"};
    final String[] forClassList = {"Parent", "Child", "Procedures", "Members", "All"};
    final JComboBox comboSearch = new JComboBox(searchList);
    final DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(forClassList);
    final JComboBox comboFor = new JComboBox(model);
    searchSelect = (String) comboSearch.getSelectedItem();
    comboSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            searchSelect = (String) comboSearch.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(searchSelect);
            switch (searchSelect) {
                case "Class":
                    model.removeAllElements();
                    model.addElement("Parent");
                    model.addElement("Child");
                    model.addElement("Procedures");
                    model.addElement("Members");
                    model.addElement("All");
                    break;
                case "Member":
                    model.removeAllElements();
                    model.addElement("Owner");
                    break;
                case "Procedure":
                    model.removeAllElements();
                    model.addElement("Owner");
                    model.addElement("Owner Parent");
                    model.addElement("Owner Users");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    comboFor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            forSelect = (String) comboFor.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(forSelect);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that whenever I try to execute this, when I select from the first combobox, `null` is being printed before the actual value. I think this is because of the `model.removeAllElements();` part of the code.

Below is the screenshot of the output.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNt3G.jpg)

Any suggestions to optimize this one is very much appreciated and welcomed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Combobox1 has two values consonants and vowels and below is the sample for action perfromed event of combobox1.

```
 private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
if(jComboBox1.getModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Vowels")){
jComboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u"}));
}else{
 jComboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"b","c","d","f"}));
}
}
```

Comment: I'll try to implement this. Thanks a lot.